# entityform list fitting to selected node

Tags: nodes, entities

After searching the web for hours I'm hoping to find the answer here for my problem.

So here is my goal:
I defined a content type, travel which contains a multiple values textfield for additional services and a entityform for booking additional services (e.g. train ticket to the travel starting point).
Each travel node has of course different number of additional services, after clicking on 'booking additional services' the form appears which should include a checkbox for each additional service to select by the customer.

I defined a text list in the form for the additional services.
Now my question is, how can I generate a list of additional services for the particular travel in my form. 
I can only set the possible values for the list in the field settings but these values depend on the particular travel!

Could you give a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal uses static forms by default, therefor one step doesn't influence another step. You are probably looking for a thing called conditional fields.

You should be able to use the [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module for this. Although I am not entirely sure it it works on all form types.